# Angular highlighting based on routerLinkActive

Tags: javascript, css, angular

i want to toggle highlighting for the routerLinkActive based on the routes, 
i have a dashboard component and both the dashboard menu item and labels menu item refer to the same component, i want to add class to the li items based on the route
for dashboard the route will be

```
http://localhost:4300/dashboard
```

and for the labels , the route will be

```
http://localhost:4300/dashboard/5d1bb53877ed8702d8a01940
```

Code for the menu item

```
 <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li [ngClass]="{ active: rlal && rlal.isActive == false }">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" (click)="loadSnippet(null)">
                    <mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                  </a>
                </li>

     <h3 *ngIf="labelList && labelList.length!=0">Labels</h3>
              <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li *ngFor="let label of labelList" [ngClass]="rlal && rlal.isActive ? 'active' : ''"
                  routerLinkActive="rlal.isActive">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', label._id]" routerLinkActive #rlal="routerLinkActive"
                    (click)="loadSnippet(label)">
                    <mat-icon>label</mat-icon>
                    <span>{{ label.label_name }} </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Routes:

```
 {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "dashboard/:labelId",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
  }
```

The highlighting works fine for the individual label items, but for the dashboard , the li is not getting highlighted

[image]

Comment: Add the `routerLinkActive` to `<li>` tag of dashboard also

Comment: If I add that, it gets highlighted with the labels , I want only one of them to be active at a time

Comment: If you check the route , both are similar and redirect to dashboard, with just one parameter, added for label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the dashboard link to be active only if there's no route parameter, you need to add `routerLinkActive` and `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` to you dashboard `li` node.

Also, you don't need to set the `active` class via `ngClass`, because `routerLinkActive` will do that for you.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a routerLink="/dashboard" (click)="loadSnippet(null)">
    <mat-icon>dashboard</mat-icon>
    <span>Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>

 ...

<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let label of labelList">
  <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', label._id]" (click)="loadSnippet(label)">
    <mat-icon>label</mat-icon>
    <span>{{ label.label_name }}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```